# Batik Swing SVG: Events on Objects in Canvas

Tags: java, svg, batik

I'm looking for a java library to use SVG for work flow presentation.

My question:

> is Batik this dynamic that you can move the objects in a svg drawing?
>   E.g. moving icons in a canvas. Something like this: [moveable
>   objects](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Batik's support for interactivity and scripting is very good. See [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/#status), where they say:

> The latest revision of Batik, release
>   1.7, is a conformant static SVG implementation and supports
>   interactivity, linking and scripting
>   features of the SVG specification.
>   This release supports a nearly
>   complete implementation of declarative
>   animation, too.

You can see [here](http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php) that they score an A+, and one of the highest overall scores compared to other SVG implementations.

The language (JavaScript) and DOM interfaces are pretty much the same as what you would find in the browser environment as well, making it possible to write very portable UI code that runs well in both contexts.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know any example to see the these features in real?

Comment: I guess I would to realize it with an Interactor. Has anyone an code example for that?